# Is `entrycget` not returning data correctly because of duplicate entries?

Tags: perl, treeview, tk-toolkit

I'm using [`entrycget`](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=entrycget) to get the relevant variable values from a widget.

```
my $selectedItem = $tree->entrycget(<label>, <data>);
```

The label is an entry indicating the level of the tree, for example the second sub-node of the node 1 of root node will be denoted as

```
'Root/node1/node2'
```

Data is the value I want to retrieve, in this case a file path. However, there are duplicate entries for data, as an example `Root/node1` and `Root/node1/node2` can both have same data value (same path).

In retrieving the value of the selected tree item, I found out that it is not returning the value correctly for some labels, typically when there is a another duplicate entry for the `data` field, as in the scenario above. Is this caused by having duplicate `data` field? How does the `entrycget` method work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `entrycget` method works on the underlying model of the tree. It maps the *path* argument (`<label>` in your question) to a particular node in that tree, and then uses the *option* argument (`<data>` in your question) to pick a field out of the node structure, returning the relevant value.

So far as the widget is concerned, duplicate *option*s are no problem as it the *path* that is the unique part (and prefixes of the path will have values set).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The issue was caused by a bug in the existing code, it is fixed now :)